# Upload to Google Cloud Storage using Signed URL returned origin not allowed on Safari only

Tags: safari, google-cloud-storage, mobile-safari

Using the [Node.js library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-nodejs) to generate signed URL and have no problem uploading files from Chrome on local machine and production. But CORS issue appears when sending the PUT request from Safari, both desktop (v13.0.5) and iOS, so far no issue with Chrome on Mac. It says `Origin https://website.com is not allowed by Acess-Control-Allow-Origin`

I am pretty sure it is somewhere related to Safari sending the request. I have double checked my API to generate the url it has all proper params (matched content type with client) also it does work on Chrome as well. The PUT request is sent using `fetch()`.

Have tried to update GCS cors config using [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors) but safari still complain origin not allowed, even now it does not work on Chrome without wildcard on `origin` and `responseHeader`. Someone mentioned on the internet Chrome fine with wildcard but Safari expects headers/origin to be explicit but can't figure out what are required headers. Have tried different variations for `responseHeader` such as *Acess-Control-Allow-Origin*, *origin*, *Origin*, *x-goog-resumable*.

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://website.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Length", "Content-Type", "Date", "Server", "Transfer-Encoding", "X-GUploader-UploadID", "X-Google-Trace"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

I have other project that run same setup and has no problem, the only difference probably the `@google-cloud/storage` npm version and using `version: 'v4'` when generating `getSignedUrl()`.

Found few on the internet saying to use `https://bucket.storage.googleapis` instead of `https://storage.googleapis/bucket` still no avail.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Safari. Did you tried to Empty Caches, enabled 3rd party cookies and disable Cross-Origin Restrictions from Develop menu?

Comment: I think I did enable 3rd party cookies on ios. And I don't think it will help most users as I can't ask everyone to clear their cache and enable 3rd party.

Comment: I asked this because this would help to issolate the root cause

Comment: No worries, I tried making the request on incognito mode as well and didn't much help.